# Nginx: Block destination IPs

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to block destination IPs using Nginx? IE someone configure a server with hostname acme.com we want to know that acme.com doesn't resolve to IP 1.2.3.4 and if it is block it

Answer (score 0):

Block / restrict IP address in NGINX.

open the NGINX config

```
sudo vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

if you have a separate virtual host configured

```
sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf
```

Block the IP

```
http{
   ...
   deny 1.2.3.4;
   ...
}

server{
    ...
    deny 1.2.3.4;
    ...
}


location / {
   deny 1.2.3.4;
}
```

Test and Restart NGINX

```
sudo nginx -t
sudo service nginx reload
```

Comment: I think it will block the source-ip, not destination..